# How to run ruby file in the background using Python and get stderr and stout?

Tags: python, ruby, windows, background, subprocess

I am developing a Python based GUI.
I need to run a ruby file  and get its output. I did it successfully using subprocess module.
But I need to run the file in the background and I need to get its output as well.

Can you please let me know how to achieve this?

Comment: In which operating system? In UNIX you can just fork and then communicate via sockets.

Comment: Hi, My operating system is Windows XP & Windows 7

Comment: This has nothing to do with the language that the command you're calling is written in - this is a Python question, not a Ruby question.